# Date.UTC() inconsistent parameters?

Tags: javascript

Why does the month parameter range from 0-11 yet the day parameter ranges from 1-31? It seems inconsistent, what is the reason?

Parameters

- year: A year after 1900.
- month: An integer between 0 and 11 representing the month.
- date: An integer between 1 and 31 representing the day of the month.

Comment: there is no good reason, it's just the way god (brendan) made it.

Comment: day: An integer between 0 and 6 representing the day of the week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the duplicate thread that was called out in the comments, I don't think there is any true reason why. The most logical reason sounds like users would end up creating an Array that has all the Months. For example, `var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", ...];`

This array would be easy to return the correct month if used properly since the Month range is 0 - 11. `return months[date.getMonth()];`

Whereas there are other methods to handle what day it is (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, ...) using the `date.getDay()` (which returns 0 - 6).